# Cloud9 NPM update error "Cannot find module 'npm log'"

Tags: npm, cloud9

Good morning!

I started a new project this morning on Cloud9, and when running "npm init", it prompted an update which I ran.

It seemed to install fine, but now when I went to "npm install" some packages, it returns the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'                                                                                
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)                                                        
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)                                                                   
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)                                                                          
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)                                                                         
    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:22:13                           
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)       
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)                                                                         
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)                                                           
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)                                                                             
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
```

Any ideas on if this is a Cloud9 bug or if it's fixable?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this very same issue with the update. I'm guessing there's some cloud9 specific issue with the way the update is handled. Ran the link below and it seems to have resolved the issue. Able to check the version and install packages now.

```
npm config delete prefix
```

Hope it helps.